# change the iwidgets::combobox selected value tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, incr-tcl

How to change the `iwidgets::combobox` selected value in tcl/tk?

```
variable check [iwidgets::combobox  .check -labeltext "aaaa" -selectioncommand aaa_update]  
eval .check  insert list 0 aaa bbb
```

I tried the following and it doesn't work. (`set ::check_tech "bbb"`)

Comment: I need something like -variable in checkbutton widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate what is selected, you use the `selection` method:

```
.check selection clear 0 end
.check selection set 1
```

The `1` is because `bbb` is the second item in the dropdown listbox, and Tcl/Tk counts indices from zero almost always (and definitely so in this case). You have to clear the selection before setting it because the underlying model of the listbox used to power the combobox supports multiple selected things at once, even though that doesn't make much sense in this case.

Comment: It didn't work.  I'm using iwidgets::combobox not ttk::combobox . Nothing was changed in the GUI

Comment: I have solved the issue. The combobox should be editable first. 
.check configure -editable true
.check selection clear 0 end
.check selection set 1

Comment: It worked when I tested, and was based directly off the stuff you wrote and the documentation, so I didn't say anything about state changes. Didn't know I'd have to look for those too…